# Change cursor in google maps v3 in runtime

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The `draggableCursor` option can be set in google.maps.Map object upon creation. Is there any way how one could set this option in runtime? Or is there any other clean way how to change the cursor in runtime? I've searched through the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) but there's nothing like `setDraggableCursor` method...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option can be set at runtime. You have to set the map options with `map.setOptions()` function. Set only the desired property in the options object:

```
map.setOptions({draggableCursor: myNewDraggableCursor});
```

Comment: great, thanks Tomik!! Note that I found out that for **getting** the value one needs to use undocumented method .get: `map.get('draggableCursor')`, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242413/google-api-v3-undocumented-method-map-get

Comment: To get the option value accessing `map.draggableCursor` should work. Although it is not directly mentioned in the reference, there's a short note in the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#MapOptions): "These options will be used to initialize the map's properties".