# google api v3 undocumented method map.get()

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've found out that the object of type google.maps.Map has method get(), which is not documented:

```
>>> map.get('draggableCursor')
"crosshair"
```

When I look in the [docs](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) the method is not there. How is it possible? Or is the function documented somewhere else and I just missed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: *"google.maps.Map class.  This class extends [MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject)"*.  The MVCObject class has a get function.