# Clean way to set MapTypeControlOptions in runtime

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Looking at the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=cs#Map) I haven't found any way to set MapTypeControlOptions **after** the maps object has been created. There's nothing like setMapTypeControlOptions method.

I invented two ways to do this, both *seem to* work:

1. directly set the object property: `map.MapTypeControlOptions = { ... }`
2. set the whole options again: `map.setOptions({ mapTypeControlOptions: { ... } })`

But I'm not quite sure this is the right way to do it. In the first case, we are modifying the object property directly, which is not very clean. In the second case, we are setting the whole options object. What will happen to the unspecified options? Will they stay the same? Will they be reset to some default? I don't know. This information is completely missing in the API reference. **We might try something and it seems to work, but as long as it is not in the specification, it might not be correct way which works in all cases!**

So I'm not satisfied with answer "it just works" :-) I ask for more authoritative reference.

Comment: map.setOptions changes only parameters that are provided as argument (it's a fact, nothing else would make any sense as well) and I think it's the proper way of doing what you want

Comment: @slawekwin, thank you. Can you cite any resource, or is it "just" your experience?

Comment: I'm not sure if I read it in any official source, but have tested it multiple times

Comment: Yes you are right - I forgot I asked similar question and the anser was the same! http://stackoverflow.com/a/8241356/684229